# CakePHP 2.3 File Upload?

Tags: cakephp, file-upload

How would I go about uploading files in CakePHP v2.3? I've tried numerous plugins, all giving different errors, as they do not fit the 2.3 MVC. I have some rough ideas, as I can get the tmp filename using `debug($this->data);`. Would I just check the filetype and move it to a directory using the `copy()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use your own code or use any other external codes for PHP such as this one:
http://www.phpf1.com/product/image-upload-script.html

External codes are placed inside *app/Vendor*.

That's the one I use with some modifications.

Anyway, don't forget to read about how to create secure upload:
http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/